# The Number of conjugate classes of a non-abelian group of order $125$

Tags: group-theory

The Number of conjugate classes of a non-abelian group of order $125$ is
$$a)29 \quad b)25\quad c)1\quad d)125$$

The answer is $29$.....a group of order $p^3$ where $p$ is prime have  $p^2+p-1$ number of conjugacy class.But my question is what is the general rule of $p^n$ where $p$ is prime. if any such rule exists?

Comment: For higher powers of $p$ it will depend on the particular group. There are vast numbers of nonabelian groups of order $p^n$ for large $n$.

Comment: if the group will be order 625 then what is the number of conjugacy class..plz explain me

Comment: As I said in my previous comment, this depends on the isomorphism class of the group. In fact a computer calculation shows that the possibilities are $49$ and $145$, depending on whether the nilpotency class of the group is $3$ or $2$.

Comment: thanks sir...it will help me further ...

Answer (score 2):

Let $k(G)$ denote the number of conjugacy classes of a finite group $G$. It is not difficult to show that if $G$ is non-abelian, $k(G) \leq \frac{5}{8}|G|$ (observe that $|G/Z(G)| \geq 4, |Cl_G(x)| \geq 2$ for $x \notin Z(G)$ and use the Class Formula). This can be generalized: if $G$ is a non-abelian $p$-group and $|G|=p^n$ (hence $n \geq 3$), then $k(G) \leq p^{n-3}(p^2+p-1)$. So much for upper bounds.

It can be proved (see [here](http://math.wvu.edu/~cpantea/pdf/conjugacy.pdf)) that if $|G|=p^ n$, then $k(G) \geq p^2 + (n-2)(p-1)$. If in addition $G$ has the property that$|G'|=p=|Z(G)|$, then $k(G)=p^{n-1}+p-1$.